# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 453: invalid start byte

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I keep getting this error when I try to load a csv file. When I try to load a csv file with only one column it works but the one I want to load is with multiple columns and rows. What am I doing wrong here.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CORRECT.csv')
```

Comment: There is some non-ascii character in the csv that can't be encoded/decoded. Try df = pd.read_csv('CORRECT.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

Comment: Try to use `encoding='cp1252'`...

Comment: @MaxU Thank you that worked perfectly